# How to run Python in session just in background?

Tags: python, c++, wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I find an interesting function `StartExternalSession`

[image]

You can see it only load the Python once and then it can calculate the expressions.

How it works?

In C++,I can use `os.system(...)` to call the python.
**In my C++ project,there is a neural networks,if I use `os.system(...)`,it will load the net again and again,it takes so much time.**

So I want to ask how to run python in session in C++?

Load the net in Python once then making prediction directly again and again no need re-import the net.

How should I do?

Comment: try os.system()

Comment: @SergAnuke I try.If only do this ,it takes so much time

Comment: IPython introduced the notion of `kernels`, a separate process to which you can send commands to evaluate and which sends back results (for example sending python code and getting python objects), avoiding the need to restart the process for every command. The protocol they use is documented here: https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html Maybe this could be of interest?

Comment: @HeroicKatora interesting design.I see, thank you! :）